# Why does cin stops for a particular input?

Tags: c++, input, console

I recently faced a problem with the `cin` statement in C++.

```
string s;
cin >> s;
cout << 1;
```

In this code 1 is printed on the screen if input to `s` is '010' and programs time limit exceeds on ideone for the same code but input being '1010'. I don't think it is due to the '\n' left in the buffer after using `cin` as this is the only instance I have taken input in the program. You can find my code at http://ideone.com/7VEsbu.

Comment: You are printing 1 with  `cout <<1;`  I suspect you meant to have `cout << s;`

Comment: `cin` is not a statement, it's an object. `cin >> s;` is a statement.

Comment: In your posted code, you are outputting "1" regardless of what the User types.  For example, I could type "Carrot" and the output will be "1".

Answer (score 0):

Problem is elsewhere. Try adding `<<endl` to the line with cout - you will get an error, but see the output. Ideone isn't flushing stream instantly after cout, and that's why you don't see your output. `endl` forces stream flush.

A wild guess would be that last while loop never terminates.

Comment: I am not the downvoter but the user has `cout << 1;` so that is why it is printing 1.  It is a simple typo.

Comment: @NathanOliver User is asking why 1 **isn't** printed when input is `1010` instead of `010`. It looks like 1 is a way to output something reliable to help with debugging, and the problem is that output isn't showed, not 1 being printed instead of something else. If you run both programs, the `1010` version hangs up without printing anything, and I guess that led the user to the conclusion that something's wrong with cin getting input.

Comment: I don't think that is what the OP is asking.  I traslate what the op is asking as *In this code 1 is printed on the screen if input to s is '010' and **[I am also getting]** programs time limit exceeds on ideone for the same code but input being '1010'.*

Comment: @NathanOliver I agree. And later he asks why `cin` is blocking his program(and suggests that it's unlikely that it's because of `\n` character that could be stuck there somewhere) - and he thinks so, because 1 is never printed from cout. I then explain that it's because stream is never flushed, but control indeed reaches the cout expression. I may be wrong, but I understand OP's thought process in such way.

Comment: @MatthewRock you are absolutely right, I am trying to print 1 just to ensure if the process completes the execution of cin statement or not, which it doesn't in case input is '0101'

Comment: @ShivamKantival and the reason is there in my answer. Your algorithm is faulty - the only reason that message's not outputted is stream flushing.